# How to fire select event programmatically

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I want to fire select event programmatically, but I do not know how. So, this is how I create selection interaction:

```
var selection = new ol.interaction.Select({
    ...
});

selection.on('select', function (event) { 
    ... here is some action or event I want to trigger
});
```

In other part of my code, I push new features to the selection:

```
selection.getFeatures().push(new_feature);
```

What I want is to trigger `select` event. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **should not** fire that event manually.  It should be up to the interaction itself to trigger it. What I would do instead is listen to a different type of event.

The `ol.interaction.Select` has a features collection, i.e. a `ol.Collection`.  That object fires `add` and `remove` events when the interaction selects features by itself, i.e. by the result of its own handler, **and** by the result of those manually pushed/removed.

Here's a snippet:

```
var featuresCollection = selection.getFeatures();
featuresCollection.on('add', function() {
  // do what you want on add
});
featuresCollection.on('remove', function() {
  // do what you want on remove
});
```

This would require a little bit more management, as the callback method are fire **per feature**, but in the end you would be able to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems like I managed to fire event with dispatchEvent method.